# How to access key:values in JSON using Java with no array names

Tags: java, arrays, json

Lets say I have a JSON array like this

```
[{"a":"1", "b":"2"}, {"c":"3", "d":"4"}]
```

I'm trying to get it in Java like this

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseBody); //resposeBody is the JSON array
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    String arr = array.get(i).toString(); //Trying to get each array like this
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(arr);
}
```

At the line of `JSONArray json = new JSONArray(arr);`I get the error

```
A JSONArray text must start with '['
```

How do I access the values?

EDIT: I mean how do I get each array and their values

Comment: Could you print out what's `responseBody` before calling `JSONArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSONArray is an array of JSONObjects.
You can try

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseBody); 
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);  
}
```

Now you can further parse the individual JSONObjects.

Comment: The fact you just told me my JSONArray is an array of JSONObjects made me solve my problem. This is my first time dealing with JSON with Java or even JSON itself. I'm able to access the keys and values now thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just do :

```
JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

In array:

```
 JSONObject myjObject = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
```